# After kernel update, stuck on purple screen but old kernel still works

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

As the title says, the new kernel doesn't work. I am on Ubuntu 12.10.

I had `3.0.39` or something like that, and when I updated to `3.0.40`, it just gave me a purple screen. However, with GRUB Customizer, I set my default boot entry to the old kernel and it works fine.

So my questions are:

1. How can I get my new kernel to work? And if not,
2. How can I delete the new kernel and make Ubuntu just boot to the old kernel?
3. And is it safe to remove the new kernel?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Boot into the working kernel.

Then investigate which kernels you have installed by doing:

```
Kver=$( uname -r)  
( dpkg -l linux-image\*; dpkg -l linux-doc\*;dpkg -l linux-headers\*) | egrep -v "$Kver"
```

This will produce a list of installed packages containing kernel-specific kernels, documents and headers, EXCLUDING the current, running kernel.

Select, from the list, the package names you want to delete, and use them as parameters to
    `sudo apt-get purge <...>`
to delete the packages cleanly.